# VLC Player, Apple TV and Time Capsule

Tags: appletv, time-capsule, vlc

I installed VLC app on my 4th generation apple TV. I also connected the VLC app to my time capsule. However the VLC app says "folder is empty".

However there are 100s of mp4 files on the time capsule.

Why can't VLC player see those files?

I installed Infuse 4 and it said exactly the same issue.

The files can easily be played using Itunes. but that requires my computer to be On during the playback.